# Azure function to return a specific string

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions

I'm new to Azure function. And I have this simple .net core code as below:

```
 public static class HttpExample
{
    [FunctionName("HttpExample")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        string name = req.Query["name"];

        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
        name = name ?? data?.name;

        return name != null
            ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
            : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
    }
}
```

This code is working fine and returns Hello, Function. However, if I'm changing it to "world" like this :

```
   string name = req.Query["World"]; //may be I would like to try multiple strings with space? Just to have fun learning.
```

It returns me:

```
  Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body.
```

How can I return any specific string using this function?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you call the function?

Comment: Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-your-first-function-visual-studio

Answer (score 3):

This is a `HttpTrigger` that you are trying to execute. The line `string name = req.Query["name"];` is going to find the query-string parameter `name` in your request and will take the value from it.

> How can I return any specific string using this function?

Whatever you assign to `name` query-string parameter, is the string that you will get in response.

For example, if you use this url in browser-

`http://localhost:7071/api/HttpExample?name=Function`

you will get `Hello, Function` in response because `query["name"]` will have value as 'Function'.

In order to return `Hello, World` you will have to provide a url something like this-
`http://localhost:7071/api/HttpExample?name=World`